# Data Import from SQL server to Excel sheet SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm working on a data export package where I move few data from sql to a excel sheet.

This package is automated to execute every weekend .

Unless i delete the previous excel file , I'm not able to run the package again as it throws the destination table is already present error.

Suggest me a way to retain the old excel file and create a new one everytime.

For example , if the earlier excel sheet was named `export_1` , the next sheet on the subsequent week should be named `export_2`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create 2 parameteres

   1. File_Path
   2. Connection_String

2.Use a Script task that creates an Excel File and Assign the values to 
  parameters "File_Path" and "Connection_String" based on the newly 
  created Excel file

3. Parameterize the 'Excel Connection'

   ConnectionString --> Connection_String
   ExcelFilePath -->  File_Path

Comment: "c:\\temp\\export_"
 + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("YEAR", GETDATE())
 + "-"
 + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("WEEK", GETDATE())
 + ".xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically pass the file name through the expressions based on the Datetime.

Ex: Filepath+Date1_mmddyy_hhmmss

Every time the file generates, It will create a file with new file name and Excel file should be passed as an expression.